# Xquery get second product sorted by name

Tags: xquery

From the following XML I want to get the nth product sorted by their @name:

```
<products>
<product name='200'>...</product>
<product name='100'>...</product>
<product name='111'>...</product>
<product name='100'>...</product>
<product name='110'>...</product>
</products>
```

I tried (to get the first, but must be also working to get the third and so on...):

```
for $d in //products/product/[1]
order by $d/@name
return $d
```

I'm not getting the correct order. Only if I remove the `[1]` it works, but then I get the hole product list.

How to do a limit here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're limiting at the wrong position (apart from the `/` before the predicate `[1]` being a syntax error).

Right now, you limit within the `for` loop's *input* specification, thus you're sorting over *a single*, namely the *first* product - which is obviously not what you're trying to achieve (and neither seems a reasonable thing to do).

To limit after performing the loop (and sorting), use a predicate wrapped *around* the loop:

```
(
  for $product in $xml//products/product
  order by $product/@name
  return $product
)[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the numeric predicate on the expression as a whole:

```
(
  for $d in //products/product
  order by $d/@name
  return $d
)[1]
```

The `for` generates the whole sequence of product elements ordered by name, the `[1]` is then an index into the sorted sequence.